# Removing datatable column causes issues with select clause

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datatable

I am working with two separate datatables, and I am trying to remove the column "NEW_IDX" of the location_dt, and then run a select clause on the location_dt. But I am getting the error "Index was outside the bounds of the array." I can remove the column after the select statement, but then I get an error later on if I try to execute a separate statement. Please let me know if more information is needed.

```vb
For Each row As DataRow In location_dt.Rows
    ' Added after edit
    ' value = row("NEW_IDX")
    ' row("IDX") = value
    row("IDX") = row("NEW_IDX")
Next
location_dt.Columns.Remove("NEW_IDX")
datarow_array = location_dt.Select("IDX > " & location_starting_index & " And IDX <= " & page_size)
```

Edit:
I was able to work around this issue by establishing a variable with the value == row("NEW_IDX") and the setting row("IDX") == value. If someone could help me understand why this would subdue my issue, that would be appreciated. I do assume the association of setting one column equal to another probably caused some pointer issues.

Comment: Where do the values of _location_starting_index _ and _page_size- come from?  when you step through your code, do they produce valid results.  At what point in the above code exactly are you getting this exception?  If you look at the table via the data visualizer are both IDX and NEW_IDX columns present?

Comment: Hi @Hursey, sorry for not providing more code. The error occurs in the select statement. location_starting_index = 0 and page_size = 100 for the first iteration. I have also confirmed that IDX and NEW_IDX are present for all records and datatables involved.